# How to lookup multiple row if the row contain same product

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Main table (Table 2) which contain the product name and product code and another table is the database (Table 1) which i query out from SQL that contain the material information for the product. I've try to use lookup function but it only manage to return Metal only.

Table 1 : Database

Table 2 : Main Table

[image]

[image]

Here is the expected result. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try something along the lines using `FILTER()` & `TOROW()` Functions.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G8`

```
=TOROW(FILTER($C$2:$D$5,(E8=$A$2:$A$5)*(F8=$B$2:$B$5)))
```

---

**Note:** Adjust your ranges as per your suit, `fill down` for the rest of the cells, `no need` to fill right, it will spill, also assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as the formulas provided above works with `MS365` **Exclusively**.

---

Since you have not mentioned about your `Excel Version`, sharing an alternative approach for earlier versions.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G8`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$D$5,
AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($C$2:$D$5)-ROW($C$2)+1)/
(($E8=$A$2:$A$5)*($F8=$B$2:$B$5)),INT((COLUMN(A1)-1)/2)+1),
MOD(COLUMNS($A$1:A1)-1,2)+1),"")
```

---

**Note:** The above formula needs to be `filled down` and `filled right`. Also depending on ones `Excel` version needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the **edit mode**.

---